# efficient way to lookup record for mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to setup and application to import emails from a CSV file.  But I want to make sure that the emails do not already exist in the table before inserting them.  Currently, the table holds 800,000 records and I am using PHP for loop to

## PHP for loop

```
foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
#mysql record check
 }
```

This somehow seems inefficient.  I have thought about using a

## PHP in_array

`bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )`

but that takes a long time to process the results and uses a lot of system resources.

Is there a better faster, simpler, way to look up multiple records?

I would like to do this in PHP only because aside from CSV I also want to import from gContacts and Hotmail using the same script. Load an array and execute insert regardless of the user selected method, just to keep things simple.

Comment: With one important caveat (but I don't think you're quite there yet), a good rule-of-thumb is NEVER *execute* a query inside a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is a reinvention of the wheel and read csv->loop->insert is at least 10x slower than LOAD DATA IN FILE

If you are concerned about Duplicates, use the IGNORE keyword.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.csv' 
IGNORE INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
 IGNORE 1 LINES  /* optional if you have a header */
```

And if you really really want to do this in PHP, create a prepared statement that executes the above

```
stmt = $dbh->prepare($q);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I would like to do this in PHP only because aside from CSV I also want to import from gContacts and Hotmail using the same script.  Load an array and execute insert regardless of the user selected method, just to keep things simple.

Comment: To keep things simple is to use LOAD DATA. YOu are just writing a horribly in efficient substitute for a rather simple mysql command.

Comment: In other words building a poor solution to an already solved problem